# Sending an array of various data types from AS3 to .NET WCF (basicHttpBinding)

Tags: c#, web-services, actionscript-3, serialization, soap

If I want to call a SOAP WebService (implemented by WCF on C#), and send as one of the parameters an array, containing many types of objects.

Example:

```
var array:Array = new Array();
array.push(1);
array.push(Number(300));
array.push("Some text");
WebService.Foo(array);
```

Over at the Web Service end I can only receive it as a `XmlNode[] OperationRequest`, which has a simple structure with no data type specified per member.

Is there a way to serialize the data and send it over the Web Service to be easily deserialized into an array containing the same objects with the same data types? (Let's assume that we can simplify the types a bit [int = int, long = number, etc])

Thanks,
Ron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'd suggest  [JavaScriptObjectNotation](http://json.org)

Comment: Yeah eventually I went with [link](http://json.codeplex.com/) JSON.NET and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the flex RPC library. There is a buildin  SOAP implementation. For this, you need to dig a little bit into the rpc lib. You need to link the rpc.swc along with the framework.swc for the array collection and so on. You don`t need a Flex application to use the rpc library.